# How can I add a column which is the sum of a level of a Multi-index, while keeping the same dimensions, in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a column in a MultiIndex Series, that is the result of the sum() of certain rows, that have some indices in common.

```py
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([
     ['warm', 'warm', 'cold', 'cold'],
     ['dog', 'falcon', 'fish', 'spider']],
     names=['blooded', 'animal'])
s = pd.Series([4, 2, 0, 8], name='legs', index=idx)
s
blooded  animal
warm     dog       4
         falcon    2
cold     fish      0
         spider    8
Name: legs, dtype: int64

s.sum(level='blooded')
blooded
warm    6
cold    8
```

What I want is to have the sum table with the same dimensions than the original table. So:

```py
s
blooded  sum
warm     6
         6
cold     8
         8
Name: legs, dtype: int64
```

So that I can append it to the initial table afterwards to obtain the following final table:

```py
s
blooded  animal    count  sum
warm     dog       4      6
         falcon    2      6
cold     fish      0      8
         spider    8      8
Name: legs, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Use `transform`... `s.groupby(level='blooded').transform('sum')`

Comment: That adds a column that is the total sum of all rows, but I don't want that.

Comment: what do you want...? transform gives exactly the expected output that you've provided

Comment: My bad, since the MultiIndex is some levels deep, I had to change the level argument in my case. But it works! Great, thanks a lot!